# AJAX rating control inside update panel leads to reload the complete page

Tags: c#, asp.net, ajax

I have used AJAX Rating control for star rating. I am trying to achieve rating without page postback, therefore I placed inside update panel but still page is used to reload.

Below is aspx page code:

```
<asp:UpdatePanel ID="UpdatePanel2" runat="server" UpdateMode="Conditional">
    <ContentTemplate>
     <cc2:Rating ID="Rating1" AutoPostBack="true" OnChanged="OnRatingChanged" runat="server"
  StarCssClass="Star" WaitingStarCssClass="WaitingStar" EmptyStarCssClass="Star"                                                              FilledStarCssClass="FilledStar">
      </cc2:Rating>
        <div style="text-align: left; padding-right: 2px;">
         <asp:Label ID="lblRatingStatus" runat="server" Text=""></asp:Label>
        </div>
     </ContentTemplate>
 </asp:UpdatePanel>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Change update mode of updatepanel from conditional to always and set `ChildrenAsTriggers="True"`. Should work in your case.

Let me know if it doesn't work.